# How to pass comma separate string in JavaScript function from Code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Code Like

**In .cs page**

```
string test = "1,2";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "OpenCenterWindow(" + test + ");", true);
```

**JavaScript funcation**

```
 function OpenCenterWindow(Ids) {
            alert(Ids);
}
```

In above I am getting alert box = 1

I have try with Encrypt and Decrypt  But I am getting error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) 
OpenCenterWindow(fBqJaxPUucc=);

But I want to 1,2 
 any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below

```
string test = "1,2";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", 
             "OpenCenterWindow('" + test + "');", true);
```

You need to pass the values in single quotes`'` or double quotest `"`

### Edit 1

When you call a function and if you have to pass a static values you always use `'` or `"` in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
string test = "[1,2]";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "OpenCenterWindow(" + test + ");", true);
```

So you wil get an integer array in client side:

```
function OpenCenterWindow(myArray) {
     alert(Ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this work.

```
  <script>
        ids="1,2";
    function OpenCenterWindow(Ids) {
        alert("herer");
    alert(Ids);
    }

        OpenCenterWindow(ids);
```